# Read file contents, store in array, add more contents to the array, then store the new array in a file C++

Tags: c++, string, file, save, addition

I have the following file (customers.txt):

```
 1  esra    doha    017987  
 2  abdulla wakra   023456
```

Problem: take new customer info from user and store it in the file, without deleting old records.

I need to read the previous contents and store them in corresponding arrays, which I did using this method:

```
void readFile()
{
ifstream infile;
infile.open("D:\\customers.txt");

for(int i = 0; infile; i++)
{
    infile >> ID[i] >> names[i] >> addresses[i]>>tn[i];
    infile.peek();
    numC++;
}

infile.close();
}
```

(numC is the number of customers, initially set as 0)

Then, I need to add a new customer. I did it as follows:

```
void add()
{
for(int i=numC; i<100;i++)
{
    cout<<"Enter your ID (or -1 to quit)"<<endl;
    cin>>ID[i];
    if(ID[i]!=-1)
    {
        cout<<"enter your name"<<endl;
        cin>>names[i];
        cout<<"enter your address"<<endl;
        cin>>addresses[i];
        cout<<"enter your telephone number"<<endl;
        cin>>tn[i];
    }
    else
        break;
}
saveFile();
}
```

saveFile() is used to store the arrays in the file after new users have been added. Here it is:

```
 void saveFile()
 {
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("D:\\customers.txt");

for(int i=0; i<numC; i++)
    outfile << ID[i] << "\t" << names[i]<< "\t"<<addresses[i]<< "\t"<<tn[i]<<endl;

outfile.close();
}
```

I am not sure where the issue is, either in add() or save(), nonetheless, after running the program, these are the contents:

```
 1  esra    doha    017987  
 2  abdulla wakra   023456
 0  0       0       0
```

Why does this happen? How can I fix it to store users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numC needs to be incremented each time you add a user in your add() routine.

Also, you might be getting the zeros at the end of the new file because your original file had a return line after the second line, so your read function tried to read in a third line even though it was blank.